# How can I backup the data of my "windows" hard disk?

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive

My problem is the following:

The mother board of my laptop is broken, but my HDD is ok.
Before changing the motherboard (which is still under warranty), I want to backup the data of my HDD.

What I have as "tools" are a desktop computer with a Linux.

The result of `sudo fdisk -l` is the following:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007c358

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   620949503   310473728   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       620951550   625141759     2095105    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       620951552   625141759     2095104   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Note: sector size is 4096 (not 512)

Disk /dev/sdf: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 15140 cylinders, total 244190646 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xdf862c23

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System                                
/dev/sdf1               1  4294967295  4294967292   ee  GPT
```

My hard disk is found: `/dev/sdf`, but cannot be mounted.
The result of `sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdf /mnt/` is the following:

```
  NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdf': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdf' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdf': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdf' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
(e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

Does someone have any clue of what's going on and how I can explore the data of my hard disk ?

May be should I wait to have a windows computer and plug my HDD on it ?

Thanks

Comment: Your `fdisk` output format is a lot different from that on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. If your Linux system is several years old you may not have up-to-date file system support. I suggest you boot a recent Linux Live system: if you use Ubuntu, you'll have access to the very useful `Disks` and `GParted` GUI applications. According to [this reference](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/partitions/partition_types-1.html) your partition type is `ee Indication that this legacy MBR is followed by an EFI header`. I have no discs of this type to check if this format is mountable.

Comment: I see. Actually the Linux system i have is an old KX Studio, which may not be the best tool to check. I tried to create a bootable usb device, but my (old) computer fails to start with it. Anyway, I think I'll just wait a little and check on a windows. I don't want to perform anything that could make me lose the data I want to back up :)

Comment: OK. There's more info [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protective_MBR). Even on your old system you can still use the very unfriendy command-line utility `sudo dd conv=sync if=/dev/sdf of=ImageFile bs=64M`. This will copy a disc sector-by-sector without mounting it. Note that `conv=sync` is crucial; otherwise, any read errors will corrupt the rest of the copy from that point. You won't be able to do much with the `ImageFile` except restore it in another `dd` call, reversing the `if=` and `of=` parameters. Make sure you remove write permission as soon as the back-up is complete.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to mount an entire block device (/dev/sdf), you have to mount only the desired partition:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdf1 /mnt/
```

Notice the 1 after sdf which indicates the first partition.

Comment: Thank you, but actually I have no access to `/dev/sdf1` the file is not found ...